# How to detect java runtime in node?

Tags: java, node.js, jar

I want to use `nodejs` to write a small command which may execute something like

```
java -jar xxx.jar
```

And I want to detect whether the user has `java` environment already. How should I do this?

Comment: You can check directly with **cmd** prompt using like this `>javac` directly you can get all option in java

Comment: Do you want to do this on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: Yep, both windows and linux.